# Fastest way to upload OHLC in C++

Tags: c++, io

I'm implementing a class to store time-series (*`OHLCV`*) which will contain methods applied to parsed file. I'm trying to figure it out if there is a faster way to upload the content of each file (*`.csv`*  which are *`≈ 40000 rows`*) into a *`std::unordered_map<std::string, OHLCV>`*. Knowing that the structure of the file is fixed (order of header):

```
.
├── file.csv
│
└── columns:
    ├── std::string datetime
    ├── float open
    ├── float high
    ├── float low
    ├── float close
    └── float volume
```

The class is implemented as follows:

```
class OHLCV {

private:

    const char* format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S";
    std::vector<long int> timestamps;
    std::vector<float> opens, highs, lows, closes, volumes;

public:

    void upload(
        const std::string& filepath,
        const char& sep,
        const bool& header
    )
    {
        std::ifstream stream(filepath);
        if (stream) {
            std::string line, timestamp, open, high, low, close, volume;

            if (header) {
                std::getline(stream, line);
            }

            while (std::getline(stream, line)) {

                std::stringstream ss(line);

                std::getline(ss, timestamp, sep);
                std::getline(ss, open, sep);
                std::getline(ss, high, sep);
                std::getline(ss, low, sep);
                std::getline(ss, close, sep);
                std::getline(ss, volume, sep);

                timestamps.emplace_back(timestamp);
                opens.emplace_back(std::stof(open));
                highs.emplace_back(std::stof(high));
                lows.emplace_back(std::stof(low));
                closes.emplace_back(std::stof(close));
                volumes.emplace_back(std::stof(volume));

            }
        }
    }

};
```

I tried to launch I bit of test to see how the OHLC::upload was performing with and these are some of the registred times:

```
[timer] ohlcv::upload ~ 338(ms), 338213700(ns)
[timer] ohlcv::upload ~ 329(ms), 329451900(ns)
[timer] ohlcv::upload ~ 345(ms), 345494100(ns)
[timer] ohlcv::upload ~ 328(ms), 328179800(ns)
```

Knowing that my optimization setting is currently at *Maximum Optimization (Favor Speed) (/O2)* and I'm testing in Release mode, could I improve the velocity of the upload without using an *`std::array`* with a *`const unsigned int MAX_LEN`* known at compile time?

Little note: Pandas (Python) takes *`≈ 63ms`* for uploading one of these files.

Comment: Just a side note: "upload" means sending data to a distant server. You just mean *load* here.

Comment: A little bit off topic, but ok I guess. Maybe, _read_ohlcv_csv_ or _read_csv_ are even better.

Comment: Have you tried to do a profile on this code to find out where it's spending the most time?

Comment: Yes, I tried to optimize this as much as possible but I could only make it as fast as Python (≈ 65ms). I'll post an update on this but main ideas to optimize it are: 1) increasing the buffer size with `input.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(buffer, sizeof(buffer));`; 2) Reserve capacity to vectors in order to avoid redundant allocations during iteration with `std::filesystem::file_size(filepath) / _LINE_LEN;`; 3) Using `string::find` instead of stringstream to split the string.

Comment: I have also tried the _`C`_ approach (_`cstdio`_) with `fopen` and `fscanf` but it is slower (≈ 85ms) than the above strategy.

Comment: When you post your update, make it an answer rather than an edit to the question.  And I meant "profile" in a very specific sense, to use a tool that tells you what amount of time is spent in each statement or function call.

Comment: Can you suggest me some resource/tutorial which explains how to implement a well known version to profile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **Increasing buffer size** to reduce number of writes. As referenced [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/setbuf), "With a user-provided buffer, reading from file reads largest multiples of *4096* that fit in the buffer"; following a test published in another answer, the optimal buffer size should be around *64KB*. Also, note that for my compiler is ok to open the file and then next to call `pubsetbuf`, but depends on compiler. I found that my optimal size is with `char buffer[65536]`.
2. **Using `string::find()`** instead of stringstream to split the string following advice provided by @rustyx [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57072375/the-fastest-way-to-read-csv-file-in-c-which-contains-large-no-of-columns-and-r).
3. Taking advantage of **knowing the structure of data** incoming (knowing columns but not number of rows). Therefore, while reading each line not checking for `std::string::npos` but instead iterating for the expected fields in line.
4. Instead of using a number of vectors equal to the number of columns, creating a `struct` which stores the records for each row. Then, initializing a `std::vector<record>` and reserving enough capacity to avoid multiple needless allocations. To approximate the number of rows I am using `std::filesystem::file_size`. Note, I am not copying the data into the vector but instead im creating the struct directly inside the vector with `records.emplace_back(std::forward<Args>(args)...)`
5. **Optimizing type conversion**: In my case I got two types of conversion: 1) string to timestamp; In this I found that *Howard Hinnat's* `date.h` library brings an incredible speed increase. 2) string to float: In this case I do not need my substring to be allocated but I simply create a `std::string_view` read by `from_chars` increase speed quite a lot.
6. `Using static size array`: Despite my initial need of dynamism, is not a secret that if you use some kind of static size array you will have the best optimization gain . In my case im using `std::shared_ptr < std::array<record, rows>> records;`.